# Ng-repeat in ng-repeat with interval and loop

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am want to make a ng-repeat in a ng-repeat and show the results of the second ng-repeat after every 3 item of the first ng-repeat. When the second ng-repeat is out of data I want to start it from the start again until the first ng-repeat is done.

Arrays:

```js
items = [
  "Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5", "Item6", "Item7", "Item8", "Item9", "Item10"
]
bars = [
  "BAR1", "BAR2"
]
```

I want my output to be:

- Item1
- Item2
- Item3
- BAR1
- Item4
- Item5
- Item6
- BAR2
- Item7
- Item8
- Item9
- BAR1
- Item10

Answer (score 2):

If you want something purely template based:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div>{{item}}</div>
    <div ng-if="($index+1) % 3 === 0">{{bars[ (($index+1) / 3 - 1)%(bars.length) ]}}</div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SHjy9/26/

Comment: This is what I need. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to create a new array and insert your `bars` elements every 3rd index :

```
var newArray = [];

items.forEach(function (item, index) {
    if (index % 3 === 0) {
       // bars.shift() will remove the first element of bars and return it
       newArray.push(bars.shift());
    }

    newArray.push(item);
});
```

Then you can `ng-repeat` on `newArray`.

Answer (score 0):

It'll most likely be simpler if you build up the list of items before iterating over them in ng-repeat, like this:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    "Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5", "Item6", "Item7", "Item8", "Item9", "Item10"
  ];

  $scope.bars = [
    "BAR1", "BAR2"
  ];

  $scope.allItems = function () {
    var arr = [], j = 0;
    $scope.items.forEach(function (item, idx) {
      if (idx > 0 && idx % 3 === 0){
        arr.push($scope.bars[j % $scope.bars.length]);
        j += 1;
      }
      arr.push(item);
    });
    return arr;
  };

}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in allItems() track by $index">
      {{ item }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```